# Laravel auth with different class names?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm trying to make a Laravel application and I'm interested in using the Auth provided by it. The problem is, english is not my main language and I feel most comfortable when all my classes/tables/columns are in my main language. As Laravel always has everything you might need, I figured it would also have a simple way to do this. Like, a `make:auth` command with arguments (I checked that, it doesn't exist).

Has anyone ever done this? Is it too much of a hassle to change everything manually? I tried it before simply using a different name for my model but it kept showing me errors that I didn't know where I should go to fix them.

If anyone knows a simpler Laravel way, or just the way with minimum work involved, I'd be really thankful.

PS: I'm using Laravel 5.1 and one of the first errors I encountered was

> FatalThrowableError in EloquentUserProvider.php line 130:
>   Class '\App\User' not found

Comment: what's the error you are facing? how you have tried? show some codes and tell me about your Laravel version.

Comment: as mentioned with in one of the answers that means its not being included with in that class showing the error so need to the top `use App\User;`

Comment: no that is not why at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a different model other than `App\User` for authentication you have to tell the Auth system this.

`config/auth.php`

```
'model' => 'Full\Name\To\Your\Other\Model',
```

Just know that when using `Auth@attempt` you can't rename 'password'. That credential must be named 'password' when passing it to `attempt` so that it knows which field it needs to not add to the query and which field to do the hash check on. In the database you can call it what ever you want but will need to update a method on that model to reflect that change, `getAuthPassword`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `use App\User;`  in Your AuthController. Hopefully This will solve your problem